# How ubuntu works on booting

Tags: startup

I am trying to understand how ubuntu (14.04 server) works at startup.
What manages the services on startup? Initctl, init.d, upstart? I'm a little bit confused about what does what.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialInitProcess.html) you can read this:

> Ubuntu 12.04+ uses a hybrid system called upstart which includes SysV runlevel specific start scripts in /etc/rc.#/ but also systemd scripts for those services which have been ported in /lib/systemd/system/. See "man 7 upstart-events" for details.